# How does the steric effect affects the electronic density of the central atom?

Tags: acid-base

For example, if you have Nitrogen attached to some methyl groups, and other attached to some ethyl groups. Why the electron releasing effect on the ethyl will be lower than for the methyl?

Answer (score -1):

Both methyl and ethyl groups have +I effect and its obvious that the ethyl groups have more electrons than the methyl groups, so in this case the present of more electron density on nitrogen atom with ethyl groups lessen the -I effect of the nitrogen atom toward the ethyl groups compared to that on the methyl groups. I think this should be the reason.

Comment: No, no, no, no.

Comment: Oh! So what's reason?

Comment: Read title of question. Also you wrote that having stronger inductive effect gives weaker effect...  Clever making it c.w. though, but it won't help I'm afraid.

Comment: Okay. I'll pounder on it ;)

Comment: CW shouldn't be used like this. If it's your answer, then it's your answer - CW is for posts where you want the entire community to pitch in.

Comment: I'll take note of that next time.

Comment: Maybe the question wasn't so clear, but thank you for your response. I was trying to understand why larger alkyl groups will have a lower electron releasing effect, you know? Why the electronic density of Nitrogen will be more negative with the Methyl than with the Ethyl or Propyl...